# Non isomorphic principal $G$-bundles

Tags: fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Remark: throughout this post we work in the smooth category, so that all manifolds, bundles, maps etc are assumed to be smooth.

An exercise asks me to show that there exists no principal $S^1$-bundle isomorphism between the Hopf bundle $S^1 \to S^3 \xrightarrow\pi S^2$ (where $S^1$ acts on $S^3$ by multiplication as usual), and the bundle with the same fiber structure but equipped with the "inverted" action $(w_1,w_2) \cdot z = (w_1z^{-1}, w_2z^{-1})$.

Aiming to reach a contradiction I suppose an $S^1$-bundle isomorphism between these two bundles exists. This is a diffeomorphism $\Phi: S^3 \to S^3$ satisfying:
\begin{array}{rc}
\pi \circ \Phi = \pi, & (*)\\[0.2cm]
\Phi(w_1 z,w_2 z) = \Phi(w_1,w_2)z^{-1}. & (**)
\end{array}

As far as I can see, the conditions $(*)$ and $(**)$ alone do not violate each other, since $\pi$ is invariant under multiplication by elements of $S^1$ (and hence their inverses) anyway. So I guess there should be issues with the diffeomorphy of $\Phi$. More particularly, I would guess smoothness/continuity of $\Phi$ (or its inverse) is an issue, since again I don't see why the equivariance condition $(**)$ would contradict the bijectivity of $\Phi$.

But I'm failing to see how to derive a contradiction here. Am I missing something simpler or am I on the right track?

EDIT:  I just realized that the book has solutions to the exercises in the appendix (I don't remember seeing this in an advanced math book so I didn't even notice they were there). I will try to add an outline of the solution to this post once I figure the details out.

EDIT 2: As promised, here is an outline of a solution. Firstly, since $\Phi$ respects the fibers by $(*)$, it must be of the form
$$ \Phi(w) = w \, \phi(w) $$
for some smooth $\phi:S^3 \to S^1$. By $(**)$ we then see that
$$ w\,\phi(wz)z = \Phi(wz) = \Phi(w)z^{-1} = w\,\phi(w)z^{-1}, $$
or in other words,
$$ \phi(w) = \phi(wz)z^2 $$
since the action is free. This is the condition that we are going to use to derive a contradiction. Since $S^3$ is simply connected, we may write
$$ \phi = e^{i\psi} $$
for some smooth $\psi : S^3 \to \mathbb R$. Thus, taking $z = z(\alpha) = e^{i\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, we get
$$ e^{i\psi(w)} = \phi(w) = \phi(wz)z^2 = e^{i\psi(we^{i\alpha})+2i\alpha}. $$
This implies that
$$ \psi(we^{i\alpha}) - \psi(w) + 2\alpha = 2\pi n(\alpha) $$
for some integer $n = n(\alpha)$. But the left hand side depends smoothly on $\alpha$, so the right hand side must as well, i.e. $n(\alpha)$ must be constant (since it is integer-valued). In fact, $n(\alpha) = n(0) = 0$. But then
$$ \psi(we^{i\alpha}) - \psi(w) = -2\alpha, $$
which is absurd, since the left hand side is bounded (since $\psi(S^3)$ is compact), while the right hand side is unbounded.

Comment: If you remove a point from $S^2$ and the corresponding Hopf circle from $S^3$, what's left does admit such a map (because $S^2-\{p\}$ is contractible, all principal bundles over it are equivalent).  So the answer must use the global topology of $S^3$ and/or $S^2$.  This makes me think of cohomology, homotopy groups, etc.  So, what tools do you have at this point in the book?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Not much. This exercise is given in the second chapter, where principal $G$-bundles are introduced. In particular it appears after the definition of principal bundle isomorphisms. The first chapter is just a recap of basic Lie theory. It might be that the book presupposes some knowledge of the topics you mention. Please also see my edit.

Comment: I didn't check if it works, but here is a possible elementary way to prove it : a section of a $G$-principal bundle $p : X \to B$  is a map $s : B \to X$ such that $p \circ s = id_B$. It should be possible to show that the Hopf bundle has no section, but its dual has sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize in advance for the long post, but, as Qiaochu mentioned, I wanted to learn something from the bare hands approach.

To set notation, I'm going to view $S^3\subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ as the pairs $(z_1,z_2)$ of unit length vectors, so $|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 = 1$.  I'm going to view $S^2\subseteq  \mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{R}$ consisting of unit length vectors.

Then the Hopf map $\pi:S^3\rightarrow S^2$ is (according to Wikipedia), given by $\pi(z_1,z_2) = (2z_1\overline{z}_2, |z_1|^2 - |z_2|^2)$.

Let $U = \{(w,t)\in S^2: t > -\epsilon\}$ and $V = \{(w,t)\in S^2: t < \epsilon\}$ where I'm thinking of $\epsilon$ as some fixed very small positive number.  Intuitively, $U$ is the northern hemisphere of $S^2$, except extended slightly below the equation, and $V$ is likewise essentially the southern hemisphere.

**Proposition 1:**  The open sets $U$ and $V$ form a trivializing cover for the Hopf bundle.

Proof: Let's start with $\pi^{-1}(U)$.  We'll start by finding a section $s_U:U\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U)$.  So, given $(w,t)\in U$, we want to associate to it $(z_1,z_2)\in \pi^{-1}(U)$.  Let's try making the simplifying assumption that $z_1$ is real and positive.

So, we are solving $(2z_1 \overline{z}_2, z_1^2 - |z_2|^2) = (w, t)$ for $(z_1,z_2)$ under the assumption that $z_1$ is real.  The first equation $2z_1 \overline{z}_2 = w$ can be solved for $z_2$, getting $z_2 = \frac{\overline{w}}{2z_1}$.  Substituting this into the equation $z_1^2 - |z_2|^2 = t$, clearing denominators, we get a quadratic in $z_1^2$.  Using the quadratic formula, together with the fact that $z_1 > 0$, we find $$z_1 = \sqrt{\frac{t+1}{2}}, \text{ and } z_2 =\frac{\overline{w}}{\sqrt{2t + 2}}.$$  Thus, our section $s_U$ is given by $s_U(w,t) = (z_1,z_2)$, with formulas for $z_1$, $z_2$ defined above. I will leave it to you to verify it's a section.

Armed with this section $s_U$, we define $f_U: U\times S^1\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U)$ by $f_U(w,t,z) = s_U(w,t)z$.  I'll leave it to you to verify that $f_U$ is an $S^1$-equivariant diffeomorphism with inverse $f^{-1}(z_1,z_2) = \left(\pi(z_1, z_2), \frac{z_1}{|z_1|}\right).$

In a similar fashion, we have a section $s_V:V\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(V)$ given by $s_V(w,t) = (z_1,z_2)$ with $$z_1 = \frac{w}{\sqrt{2-2t}} \text{ and } z_2 = \sqrt{\frac{1-t}{2}}.$$  This gives a trivialization $f_V:V\times S^1\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(V)$ given by $f_V(w,t,z) = s_V(w,t)z$ with inverse $f_V^{-1}(z_1,z_2) = \left(\pi(z_1,z_2), \frac{z_2}{|z_2|}\right).$  $\square$

**Proposition 2**:  The composition $f_V^{-1}\circ f_U$ maps $(w,t,z)$ to $(w,t, \frac{\overline{w}}{|w|} z$.

**Proof**:  We compute.  \begin{align*} f_V^{-1}(f_U(w,t,z)) &= f_V^{-1}( s_U(w,t)z) \\ &= f_V^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{t+1}{2}}z, \frac{\overline{w}}{\sqrt{2t+2}}z\right) \\ &= \left(\pi\left(\sqrt{\frac{t+1}{2}}z,\frac{\overline{w}}{\sqrt{2t+2}}z\right) , \frac{\frac{\overline{w}}{\sqrt{2t+2}}z}{\left|\frac{\overline{w}}{\sqrt{2t+2}}z\right|}\right) \\&= \left(w,t, \frac{\overline{w}}{|w|} z\right).\end{align*}   $\square$

Using this, we can view $S^3$ as $(U\times S^1) \coprod (V\times S^1)/\sim$ where $(w,t,z)\in U\times S^1$ is identified with $(w,t, \frac{\overline{w}}{|w|} z)\in V\times S^1$ for any $t\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.   Using this description, the projection map $\pi$ is simply projection onto the $w$ and $t$ coordinates.

Now, let's show $\Phi$ cannot exist.  To that end, let's assume $\Phi$ does exist.  Note $(\ast)$ implies that $\Phi$ maps fibers to fibers.  In particular, in our above description, $\Phi$ is given by a pair of maps $\Phi_U:U\times S^1\rightarrow U\times S^1$, $\Phi_V:V\times S^1\rightarrow V\times S^1$ which respect $\sim$.

Since $\Phi$ preserves each fiber, $\Phi_U(w,t,z) = (w,t,\phi_U(w,t,z))$ for some function $\phi_U$.

**Proposition 3**:  The function $\phi_U$ has the property that $\phi_U(w,t,z) = \phi_U(w,t,1)z^{-1}$.

**Proof**:  Using $(\ast\ast)$, we know that $$\Phi_U(w,t,z) = \Phi_U((w,t,1)z) = \Phi_U(w,t,1)z^{-1} = (w,t,\phi_U(w,t,1))z^{-1} = (w,t,\phi_U(w,t,1)z^{-1}).$$  On the other hand, $\Phi_U(w,t,z) = (w,t,\phi_U(w,t,z))$.  Thus $\phi_U(w,t,1)z^{-1} = \phi_U(w,t,z)$ as claimed.  $\square$

Of course, the above discussion applies equally well to  $\Phi_V$.  In particular, Proposition 3 is also true for $\phi_V$.

We'll now use the fact that $\Phi$ is well defined to find a relationship between $\phi_U$ and $\phi_V$.

**Proposition 4:**  We have $\phi_U(w,0,1)\overline{w} = \phi_V(w,0,1)w$.

**Proof**:  Since $(w,t,z)\in U\times S^1$ is identified with $(w,t,\frac{\overline{w}}{|w|}z)$ in $V\times S^1$, we must have $[\Phi_U(w,t,z)] = [\Phi_V(w,t,\frac{\overline{w}}{|w|} z]$ for all $(w,t,z)$ with $t\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon).$  Set $t=0$ (so $|w| = 1$) and set $z=1$.

Now, $\Phi_U(w,0,1) = (w,0,\phi_U(w,0,1))\in U\times S^1$, and so $(w,0,\phi_U(w,0,1))\sim (w,0, \overline{w} \phi_U(w,0,1))\in V\times S^1$.  Since $\Phi_V(w,0, \overline{w} ) = (w,0, \phi_V(w,0, \overline{w}))$, the condition that $\Phi$ respect $\sim$ implies that $$(w,0,\overline{w}\phi_U(w,0,1)) = (w,0,\phi_V\left(w,0,\overline{w})\right).$$

Using Proposition 3 on the last coordinate, we conclude $\phi_U(w,0,1)\overline{w} = \phi_V (w,0,1)w$ as claimed.  $\square$

We are now ready to reach a contradiction.  Namely, we claim that $\phi_U(w,0,1)\overline{w} =\phi_V(w,0,1)w$ is contradictory.  Viewing $\phi_U(\cdot,0,1):S^1\rightarrow S^1$, the degree of this map must be $0$ because $\phi_U$ extends to the disk $U$.  Likewise, the degree of $\phi_V(\cdot,0,1)$ is $0$.  Thus, the maps $\phi_U(\cdot, 0,1)$ and $\phi_V(\cdot,0,1)$ are homotopy to constants.  It now follows from the equation $\phi_U(w,0,1)\overline{w} = \phi_V(w,0,1)w$ that the maps $w\mapsto \overline{w}$ and $w\mapsto w$ are homotopic.   This is absurd since one has degree $1$ while the other has degree $-1$.  This contradiction establishes that $\Phi$ cannot exist.

Comment: I tried to avoid as much algebraic topology as I could, but I don't see how to avoid it at the end.  I also expect that my contradiction is "isomorphic" to the one the book arrives at, but I'm not seeing it.  Of course, the $\overline{w}$ vs $w$ issue is the same as a $w^2$ on one side, but the book involves a map $S^3\rightarrow S^1$, while I've got maps from $U,V$ to $S^1$...

Comment: Can I ask why you referred to Wikipedia for Hopf map definition? (It seems to me that you didn't know coordinate expression of that map? that I believe surly isn't right.)

Comment: Oh wow, nice work! And thanks for typesetting all of it. But I guess the approach given in the book also uses some topology. Namely, when writing $\phi = e^{i\psi}$ for some function $\psi: S^3 \to \mathbb R$. I don't really know how to prove this but I would guess one needs topology since simple connectedness is involved here. That being said, this seems "intuitively correct" enough for me to accept it.

Comment: @C.F.G:  I actually don't have the coordinate expression for the Hopf map memorized.  Generally speaking, the existence of the map and its key properties are much more important than the formula for the map.

Comment: @MSDF:  Yes, when the book passes from $\phi$ to $\psi$, it is using some covering space theory. I find the geometric picture of winding numbers and degree a lot more intuitive than coverings (at least until you get used to them), so I tried to find a proof that avoided covering spaces entirely.  That said, as I mentioned in my first comment, I wouldn't be surprised to learn that I didn't actually do anything different from the book.

Answer (score 3):

I think the "standard" argument would be that the Hopf fibration is classified by a nontrivial element of $H^1(S^2, S^1) \cong H^2(S^2, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ (I think more specifically by twice a generator but don't quote me on that) so the inverted bundle is presumably classified by the negative of this element, and since $\mathbb{Z}$ has no $2$-torsion no such bundle is equivalent to its inverse. Probably there's something to learn from trying to show that the diffeomorphism $\Phi$ doesn't exist more concretely though.

Comment: (By the way, the Euler class of the Hopf bundle is a generator of $H^2$, as follows, e.g., from the Gysin sequence).

Comment: @Jason: hmm, I was hedging because it looked like one of the Hopf bundle and the unit tangent bundle $S^1 \to SO(3) \to S^2$ should be twice the other but I wasn’t sure which.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But this argument is way above my head though (and also way outside the scope of the book I'm reading, which is essentially an introduction to principal $G$-bundles).